# Code witn subprocess, multiprocessing doesn`t work

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I want my Telegram bot to start and when a new record appears in the database, it should stop working and perform one function. But it doesn't work, only one 'ok' is written after I stop the code. Main - my Telegram bot.

```
import datetime as dt
import time as t
import main as m
import database as dat
import subprocess as s
import multiprocessing as mp

PROCESS = True

def main1_func():
    p = s.Popen(['python', 'main.py'])

def main2_func():
    global PROCESS
    print('ok')
    while True:
        d = dat.data()
        da = dt.datetime.now()
        date = da.strftime('%y%m%d%H%M')
        date = int(date)
        per = d.perev(date)
        print('ok')
        if per != []:
            PROCESS = False
            m.perevirka_1()
            t.sleep(2)
            PROCESS = True
            p1.start()
        t.sleep(600)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('ok')
    p2 = mp.Process(target = main2_func)
    p1 = mp.Process(target = main1_func)
    p2.start()
    p1.start()

    while PROCESS:
        pass
    p1.terminate()
```

I tried subprocess? threading and multiprocessing

Comment: Can you make this a [mre] that people who aren't you can run? (Nobody else has a `main` or a `database`)

Comment: Do you realize that `PROCESS` being tested by your main process *is not the same `PROCESS`* being modified by `main2_func`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i think the code of main and database does not need to be specified, since I have provided basic information about them

Comment: @Booboo oh, ok i shall correct it. But I don`t think that`s the reason

Comment: @МаксимГера, if "providing basic information" requires someone else to write their own example before they can see the problem theirselves or test an answer, you're creating an unreasonable expectation. The point of a [mre] is to make it as easy as possible for people to reproduce the problem in a debugger (or other instrumented environment) or check their work; needing to write a new database module or main module is not "as easy as possible" -- and if it were, you could just put a stub or simplified version in the question, or refactor the question's code to no longer need them at all.